# JQuery validation plugin keeps refreshing page

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the validation plugin for jQuery to validate a form before making an Ajax call, but for some reason every time I submit the form the page refreshes. Here is my validation function:

```
//Invite form validation
$("#inviteForm").validate({
//Rules for invite validation
rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
//Messages to print if validation fails
messages: {
            name: "Please provide your friend's name.",
            email: "We cannot contact your friend without a valid email address.",
        },
//What to do when validation succeeds
submitHandler: function(form) {
            //Form is valid, make Ajax call
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/invite/process',
            data: $("#inviteForm").serialize(),
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(data, textStatus ,XHR) {
                $("#inviteModal").html(data);
                if(data.indexOf("Thank you") >= 0 ){
                    invites -=1;
                    $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
                    $("#inviteModal").fadeOut(5000);
                }
            }
            });
            return false;
        }
});
```

I have it inside a `$(document).ready`, but I didn't post the whole thing because I have a few other functions in there. And this is the code for the form:

```
<!--// MODAL: INVITE //-->
<div id="inviteModal" class="modal" style="display: none">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var invites = <?php echo $user->getInvitesLeft(); ?>;
if(invites < 1){

$("#inviteModal").html("You have no invites left. You can get more by increasing your score.");
}
else{
$("#inviteModal").html("<h2>Please enter the specified information for the friend you wish to invite. </h2>"+
   "<form id=\"inviteForm\" >"+
   "<p>Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"></p>"+
   "<p>Email: <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\"></p>"+
   "<p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Invite\"></p>"+
   "</form>");
}

</script>
</div>
```

Whenever I submit the form it refreshes the page without executing the Ajax call and tacks the form data on to the URL, such as ?name=bobby&email=williamrump%40aol.com&submit=Invite. Why might it be refreshing the page without making the Ajax call, and what might I be able to do to prevent it?

Comment: you should be more specific, could you post your form structure for better analysis ? 

Edit : Is this javascript code inside a $(document).ready ?? because if it's calling this function before the document be loaded, the selector may not find your form, and this is why it isn't working properly

Comment: It is inside a document ready, I just didn't post that before.

Comment: are you creating the form *after* trying to attach the validator?

Comment: @DvirAzulay that was it, I moved the form tags outside my javascript and changed it to dynamically alter the form instead of trying to get rid of the form if they aren't allowed to invite users.

Comment: @jaimerump: great! I'm glad that fixed it. I added that and some other tips I was writing regarding this kind of issues, and also included the fact that while writing it you seem like have sorted it with that feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are creating your form *after* trying to attach the validator.
This, is one of the few reasons that may cause this:
I would check for:

- `document.ready()` around jQuery code, to make sure you are attaching the validator events *after* creating it.
- If you are creating the form through JavaScript, make sure that code is executed before attaching the validator events.
- Check for JavaScript errors. They may stop the execution of the rest of your JavaScript and prevent it from attaching the validator events to the form.
- Check for extra `,` in the options object sent to the validator. Some browsers (like IE) might fail with it.
- Try to add a `console.log()` on your submit handler, to see if anything goes through to your validator.

*Last minute note*: Seems like my first suggestion, also provided in the comments to your question was the issue. So you may take the rest as future check list for this kind of issues :)